# Is AWS Organizations a centralized policy management system

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

To give some background here, my company has not implemented AWS Organizations. We have this problem where many of the same environments (accounts): Prod, Dev, and QA all have the same policies and users. When one policy is updated in one environment, we must either manually go into the others or run a script depending on what's being done.

Is this one of the use cases for AWS Organization? We can update one central policy and "append" that policy to the Units? If this is not the exact usage of AWS Organization, is there another way we can duplicate this action without the need to interface with the AWS API?

Thanks!

Comment: Users can assume cross account roles, those account roles can be created using infrastructure as code, eg CloudFormation or Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this question now, we now leverage [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/) for this.